# Devexpress. How to get crosshair label text

Tags: winforms, charts, devexpress

I'm using Devexpress charts for winforms. I'm using the SwiftPlotSeriesView for preformance, but since the hittesting is off for that type I can't get the clicked point on the chart. That's why i whould like to get the text value from the crosshair label so that i know where in my series the user clicked. I nope my explanations is good enough :)

[image]
Any help?

Comment: Post some image to show what exactly you need, otherwise there may be misunderstanding.

Comment: When you edit the post, please care notifying the users by comment with @Username, otherwise they won't be notified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of work we concluded that this is not possible in Devexpress SwiftPlotSeries.